# Problems with IAX Clients in Realtime Asterisk

Tags: mysql, odbc, asterisk

I have a problem with the iax clients when I try to used them with dynamic realtime, I can stablish a call with an extension

I'am  using Centos 6, asterisk 11 and mysql

The only visible problem is when a iax client try to register  asterisk log this:

CLI> ...WARNING: chan_iax2.c:4452 realtime_peer: Failed to parse sockaddr '(null)' for ipaddr of realtime peer 'ipaddr'

I use this table for iax clients:

+------+----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
| name | username | type   | host    | secret | context | disallow | allow |
+------+----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
| 1001 | 1001     | friend | dynamic | 1001   | agents  | all      | ulaw  | 
| 1002 | 1002     | friend | dynamic | 1002   | agents  | all      | ulaw  | 
+------+----------+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-------+

regards

Answer (score 0):

The warning message stop when is establish the parameter rtcachefriends in the general section of iax.con file:

/etc/asterisk/iax.conf

```
[general]
rtcachefriends=yes
```

The call could not be establish because a mistake in the extconfig.conf:

Different from 'sip' for 'iax' one have to explicitly specify 'peers' and 'users'

/etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf:

---

```
sippeers => mysql,asterisk,sippeers
extensions => mysql,asterisk,extensions
iaxpeers => mysql,asterisk,iaxfriends
iaxusers => mysql,asterisk,iaxfriends
```

---